# Deutsches Wort für "eye-service", oder im Allgemeinem, dem lateinischen "pseudo-" Prefix?

Tags: english-to-german

Und im Allgemeinem suche ich ein Äquivalent für das lateinische "pseudo-"Präfix.

Zum Beispiel: "pseudo-arbeit" wäre das englische Wort für "eye-service".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Schein**-, wie in Scheinselbständiger.

Weitere Möglichkeiten: Als-Ob-Dienstleisung oder Alibiarbeit. *Alibi* ist aber wohl auch lateinischen Ursprung, jedoch wie *Pseudo* gut in die Sprache integriert.